# What does "he might be pitching you on the opposite of what he said" mean?

Tags: idiom-request

Here is the text:

> He’s a salesman, and he’ll say what he thinks his customers want to hear in the moment. Sure, he might be **pitching you on the opposite** of what he said last week, but he can explain that away, too. Just let him talk a bit longer.

What is the writer implying here?

Is Mr. Trump according to the author trying to make us believe the opposite of what he actually said or is it something different?

What does "pitch someone on the opposite" mean?

Here is the link to the article:https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2023/04/12/trump-tucker-carlson-fox-news/

Comment: It says "the opposite of what he said *last week*". In other words, Trump will say whatever is demanded by the circumstances, without caring about consistency with anything he may previously have said.

Comment: That article is behind a paywall. Why not copy the relevant text?

Comment: [P{lease, please learn the question forms: What is the writer implying? What does the writer imply?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no expression "pitch someone on the opposite". This is just the verb "pitch" with the word "opposite" in the same sentence.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pitch):

> **pitch** *transitive verb*
> **3 a :** to present or advertise especially in a high-pressure way : plug, promote
> **b :** to attempt to persuade especially with a sales pitch
> **c :** to present (a movie or program idea) for consideration (as by a TV producer)

So the writer is saying that Trump will try to convince you do or believe something which is opposite to the what he'd tried to convince you of just a week before.